# Editing word documents in a web page

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

I realise this question has been asked many times before but a lot of them are old now without an answer.

I have a need for users to be able to edit word documents from my web page.

Are there any editors, or components, that will allow me to do this?

A bit of background, the user will be able to upload a word document to my site and then view/edit it from there.  There will be no requirement for the user to download the document again but ideally I'd like to keep the document as a word doc at my end.

Cheers

Comment: Not sure if you'd consider integrating with Google Docs.

Comment: No they won't go for that worse luck.  This has to be a total home grown solution.

Answer (score 1):

A little pricey, but the .NET Server version of [TX Text Control](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/) allows editing of .doc and .docx documents within a browser.  (I have the standalone .NET Pro version.)

Here's a much cheaper one: [Cute Editor](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/), but I have never used it.

Comment: Certainly a possibility but I don't like the fact that you need to install something to make it work on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can* do what you want with the OpenXML SDK and some XSLT (you can convert to/from docx or WordML to html) but it's not easy, and you'd have a great deal of difficulty retaining fidelity if you have much more than very simple documents.

Comment: Yeah and we have the added complexity of Word 2003 just to make life not worth living anymore

Comment: If you can get the converter installed for the end users, that isn't so big a deal. I'm wrapping up a project that requires me to append one document to another (keeping separate headers/footers/styled between each) and it's much more complicated than I had hoped.